# Need help to 3D plot of the letter W

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

> Generate a 3 D list plot using the image data from a binarized size - 200 letter "w" as heights

```
    ListPlot3D[
Reverse[
ImageData[
Binarize[Rasterize[Style["W", 200]]]]]]
```

[image: need to create this plot]

> Need to create this plot

[image]

> but the result that I created is mismatching

Comment: Ratheesh, you may get a better help with your homework assignment if you write precisely why your solution is "mismatching".

Comment: code giving the output. but, when i check it in the website it shows "the code wrong". this is the link to that page, question number 24.11 https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/an-elementary-introduction-to-the-wolfram-language/24-more-forms-of-visualization.en.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it's the `Mesh` that you want to match. Try this

```
ListPlot3D[ImageData[Binarize[Rasterize[Style["W", 200]]]], 
 Mesh -> 10]
```

> [image: w]

Comment: thank you for helping out. this code giving the output. but, when i check it in the website it shows "the code wrong". this is the link to that page question number 24.11 https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/an-elementary-introduction-to-the-wolfram-language/24-more-forms-of-visualization.en.html

Comment: @Ratheesh sorry, but I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: thank you for your help. by the way I'm creating a repository for questions and answers in GitHub. I'm inviting u to check that https://github.com/Ratheesh-Babu-S/Wolfram-Mathamatica-tutorial      :-)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your system is using a different font and thus your letter "W" looks different.
You can specify the `FontFamily` as an `Option` to `Style`, see e.g.

```
ListPlot3D[ImageData[Binarize[Rasterize[Style["W", 200, FontFamily -> "Times"]]]]]
```

This produces the following plot

[image]